# How to align buttons in the MdDialog md-dialog-actions block

Tags: angular, angular-material

In the MdDialog's md-dialog-actions block, is it possible to align a button on the left while there are two buttons aligned to the right?

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zhzxqPANDZagcN1znTzL?p=preview) of some stuff I'm trying to do.  Say, on the first modal, how do I separate the Yes and No buttons? (See the common-model.component.ts file) (This plnkr has some other issues to it that I'm still working on. But it doesn't involve this question.)

```
import { Component }   from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef } from "@angular/material";

@Component({
    selector: 'common-modal',
    template: `
      <h2 md-dialog-title id="modal-title">{{ title }}</h2>
      <md-dialog-content>
        <p class="dialog-body" id="modal-message">{{ message }}</p>
      </md-dialog-content>
      <md-dialog-actions align="right">
        <button md-raised-button 
                md-dialog-close 
                id="modal-close-btn">
          {{ buttonOptions.closeText }}
        </button>
        <button md-raised-button 
                *ngIf="buttonOptions.enableNext" 
                id="modal-next-button"
                (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">
          {{ buttonOptions?.nextText }}
        </button>
      </md-dialog-actions>`,
})
export class CommonModalComponent {
    /**
     * {string} The text for the header or title of the dialog.
     */
    title: string;
    /**
     * {string} The text for the body or content of the dialog.
     */
    message: string;
    /**
     * closeText  {string}  The text of the close button. (No, Done, Cancel, etc)
     * nextText   {string}  The text of the confirming button. (Yes, Next, etc)
     * enableNext {boolean} True to show the next button. False to hide it.
     */
    buttonOptions: {
        closeText: string,
        nextText?: string,
        enableNext: boolean
    };


    constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<CommonModalComponent>) { }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can align `md-dialog-actions` with the `align` attribute which is available `Material 2.0.0-beta.2` on words.  Update version if you are not on the latest. You can use `"end"` or `"center"` to align.

```
<md-dialog-actions align="end"> ... </md-dialog-action>
```

If you want to align buttons individually, it needs custom styles on them. Use custom styles on buttons to separate them as well (This may be fixed in next material version)

Comment: Keep in mind, `align` is not supported by HTML5. Put `.mat-dialog-actions { justify-content: flex-end; }` to your .css file.

Answer (score 19):

May be it's too late to reply here, but i have some additions to make to the solution provided by @PrazSam. Hope it helps !
You can add a span in-between the buttons which will create an empty space and align the pre space buttons to left and post space buttons to right of the dialog container.
something like below : 
MdDialogHTML

```
<md-dialog-actions align="end">
<button md-button color="primary">+ MORE VARIANTS</button>
<span class="spacer"></span>
<button md-button color="primary">SAVE</button>
<button md-button color="warn" (click)="dialogRef.close()">CANCEL</button>
```

MdDialogCSS

```
.spacer {flex: 1 1 auto;}
```